# Running a Python script with the PyMySQL module via PHP exec()

Tags: python, php

I have a PHP script that calls a Python script using `exec()`. The Python script uses a non-native module, PyMySQL. To test it, I executed the script in the terminal as an anonymous web user, using user `www-data` using the command:

`sudo -u www-data ./hello.py`

I get a "ModuleNotFoundError."

The python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pymysql.cursors
print('Hello world')
```

If I comment out the `import` statement, the script will run fine, otherwise, the whole script fails. How can I get the python script to run with the extra module, even when it is invoked by an anonymous web user via PHP `exec()`?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError` is explanatory enough. This package is not available for this python execution. Possibly it is not installed either globally or locally for this user. Possibly you have installed it using pip locally for your personal user account only. For example, do you find the module when executing with your primary user account?

Comment: Right. I installed it with my personal user account, as I only have access to the server via a shared hosting account.

Comment: I'm surprised you have access to `sudo -u www-data` on a shared hosting account.  Seems very insecure to me.

Comment: I don't have access to sudo on the server, but I do have access to it in my local testing environment.